# Given a shuffled poker deck, if we draw one card at a time from the top and stop when

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given a shuffled poker deck, if we draw one card at a time from the top and stop when we draw an ace, and denote $X$ as the number of cards we have drawn, what is $P(X=10)$?

I am thinking $P(\text{ace})$, which is $\frac{18472}{54145}$ but the system does not accept it.

Can someone please help me understand the questions even?

Comment: The question is asking, what is the probability that the first time you draw an Ace will be the 10th card? In doing this problem, I would first compute the probability of not getting an ace on the first $9$ cards.

Comment: How did you get your answer?  We can't see what is wrong if you don't show the work.

Comment: The number $\frac{18472}{54145}$ is an answer to the question of "What is the probability that within five draws you draw at least one ace, written more legibly as $1-\frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$.  That probability is entirely unrelated to the current problem.  Here we are not asking for "what is the probability of at least one ace" and we are not drawing five cards...  We are asking for the probability that very specifically the first nine cards drawn are not aces and the tenth card drawn is an ace.

Comment: If you write something like $P(\text{ace})$, then you *really* should be clearer as to what the event means in this context...  Just writing "$P(\text{ace})$" with no other context, we don't know if you are talking about the probability of having a specific card be an ace, or the probability of getting at least one ace within a certain number of trials, or something else entirely.  It should be clear that these probabilities have nothing to do with one another and will have different answers.  Don't just blindly use values, stop and think about what the values mean and if it a correct context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw nine non-aces followed by an ace.  The chance the first card is not an ace is $\frac {48}{52}$.  Assuming it is not an ace, the chance the second card is not an ace is $\frac {47}{51}$ and so on.  After nine non-aces, the chance of an ace is $\frac 4{43}$. 
 Multiply them all together and you are there.

Comment: Why after nine non-aces, the chance of ace is 4/43?  is 48/52 * 47/51 *46/50 * 45/49 * ...   40/44?* =4/43?

Comment: No, after nine non-aces there are $43$ cards left in the deck, $4$ of which are aces.  The product in your comment is the chance you get nine non-aces in a row to start.